# Why the fixed order of vocabulary in word embedding matter?

Tags: python, pytorch, word-embedding

When I went through this [Pytorch word embedding turtorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nlp/word_embeddings_tutorial.html) recently, I noticed that the order of vocabulary will have an influence on the predicting result.

Here's an example code to explain the problem, which is modified from Robert Guthrie's previous code.

```
import torch
import torch.autograd as autograd
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as functional
import torch.optim as optim

torch.manual_seed(1)

CONTEXT_SIZE = 2
EMBEDDING_DIM = 4

test_sentence = r"""<s> The mathematician ran . <\s>
<s> The mathematician ran to the store . <\s>
<s> The physicist ran to the store . <\s>
<s> The philosopher thought about it . <\s>
<s> The mathematician solved the open problem . <\s>""".split()

# build a list of tuples.  Each tuple is ([ word_i-2, word_i-1 ], target word)
trigrams = [([test_sentence[i], test_sentence[i + 1]], test_sentence[i + 2])
            for i in range(len(test_sentence) - 2)]

# fix the order of vocabulary
# if the sorted() is removed, the predicting result will be unstable.
vocab = sorted(list(set(test_sentence)))
word_to_ix = {word: i for i, word in enumerate(vocab)}


class NGramLanguageModeler(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, context_size):
        super(NGramLanguageModeler, self).__init__()
        self.embeddings = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(context_size * embedding_dim, 128)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(128, vocab_size)

    def forward(self, inputs):
        embeds = self.embeddings(inputs).view((1, -1))
        out = functional.relu(self.linear1(embeds))
        out = self.linear2(out)
        log_probs = functional.log_softmax(out, dim=1)
        return log_probs


loss_function = nn.NLLLoss()
model = NGramLanguageModeler(len(vocab), EMBEDDING_DIM, CONTEXT_SIZE)
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)

# train the model
for epoch in range(20):
    for context, target in trigrams:
        context_indices = [word_to_ix[w] for w in context]
        context_var = autograd.Variable(torch.LongTensor(context_indices))

        model.zero_grad()
        log_probs = model(context_var)

        loss = loss_function(log_probs, autograd.Variable(torch.LongTensor([word_to_ix[target]])))

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

context_tuple = ("<s>", "The")

context_indices = [word_to_ix[w] for w in context_tuple]
context_var = autograd.Variable(torch.LongTensor(context_indices))

model.zero_grad()
log_probs = model(context_var)

sims = []
probs = []
candidates = ["philosopher", "physicist"]

# to calculate which word is closer to mathematician according to cosine similarities
related_embedding = model.embeddings(autograd.Variable(torch.LongTensor([word_to_ix["mathematician"]])))

for word in candidates:
    # Probability
    probs.append(log_probs[0][word_to_ix[word]])
    # Cosine similarity
    embedding = model.embeddings(autograd.Variable(torch.LongTensor([word_to_ix[word]])))
    sims.append(functional.cosine_similarity(embedding, related_embedding))

print("Predicted word (probability): %s" % (candidates[0] if probs[0] > probs[1] else candidates[1]))
print("Predicted word (cosine similarity): %s" % (candidates[0] if sims[0] > sims[1] else candidates[1]))
```

If the sorted() function of the `vocab` variable is removed, the result will be different. Since I already fixed the Pytorch's random seed, why the result is irreproducible?